# Defining default values for subclassed NumericUpDown control

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

I am subclass my NumericUpDown controls to name xNumericUpDown which appears now on top of toolbox in my IDE.
I would like that my new control set default values differently from original control.
Most important will be DecimalPlaces=2, Minimal=Decimal.MinValue, Maximal=Decimal.MaxValue and Increment=0.

I suppose for that I should make right properties in subclass. 
So I try as such:

```
 <DefaultValue(Decimal.MinValue), _
  Browsable(True)> _
Shadows Property Minimum() As Decimal
    Get
        Return MyBase.Minimum
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        MyBase.Minimum = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But this don't work.
When placed to form my control have properties of original NumericUpDown.
Minimum=0, Maximum=100, DecimalPlaces=0, Increment=1.

How can I get desired functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Vb.Net very well but here is c# where you create your own control giving the properties your default values.

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public MyNumericUpDown():base()
    {
        DecimalPlaces = 2;
        Minimum = decimal.MinValue;
        Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
        Increment = 1;
    }
}
```

As I said I don't know vb.Net but I think this is the translation...

```
Public Class MyNumericUpDown Inherits NumericUpDown
{
    Public Sub New()
    {
        MyBase.New()
        DecimalPlaces = 2
        Minimum = decimal.MinValue
        Maximum = decimal.MaxValue
        Increment = 1   
    }
}
```

If you don't have a need to use NumericUpDown with constant defaults then creating a custom control wouldn't be of value and you should simply create different objects for each need.

```
    numericUpDown1 = New NumericUpDown()

    ' Set the Minimum, Maximum, and other values as needed.
    numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2
    numericUpDown1.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue
    numericUpDown1.Minimum = decimal.MinValue
    numericUpDown1.Increment = 1
```

You would only use the `Shadow` keyword to hide implementations in a base class for a class that you derived.

Comment: Hi Harrison, I am OK with C#. Problem of your example is that this overwrite settings for ALL MyNumericUpDown at program start but not all MyNumericUpDown havent same purpose. I have to input also Integers, without DecimalPlaces, and different properties too for different situations...

Comment: @user973238 I thought you wanted to create a custom control with specific properties to use frequently.  If not, I'm not sure what you are looking for.  If they don't have _anything_ in common why not just use the base class and set the properties as needed?

Comment: I try to do that (set different properties according to concrete needs) and I give example how I do that in my question but problem is that this don't work. Maybe I declare and use porperty incorrect?

Comment: @user973238 I updated my answer to hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: I don't know, that simply don't work. I use shadow keyword in those four properties in my subclass but when I place new myNumericUpDown to Form a values of those properties are not those which I set as <DefaultValue> but those from original NumericUpDown...

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultValue` is only an attribute used by the designer to determine whether or not to serialize the data (and make it bold in the PropertyGrid).  In your code, you would still have to "set" the default value yourself.

```
Public Class xNumericUpDown
  Inherits NumericUpDown

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.DecimalPlaces = 3
  End Sub

  <DefaultValue(3)> _
  Public Shadows Property DecimalPlaces As Integer
    Get
      Return MyBase.DecimalPlaces
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
      MyBase.DecimalPlaces = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Lars, I dig a bit on problem and still didn't find a way to set default/initial property values for my control. What you suggests (in New) is different, this set values for all such controls what is not wanted.

Comment: And More! I have now Minimal set to "-79228162514264337593543950335" what is Decimal.MinValue. When I rightclick on property grid and choose "Reset" on that value error message appears: "Object of type 'System.Single' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'", when I try a same on property "Increment" this: "Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'". Is this normal? In designer file those values are written like arrays of 4 integers!

Comment: @user973238 I updated the example.  Hopefully it's a little clearer now.  Not sure what you expected from Decimal.MinValue since that's what you were specifying.  As you can tell, Decimal is a big number.  What's unclear to me still is your comment: `this set values for all such controls what is not wanted.`  That's the definition of a default value, so why do you want a default value otherwise?  In my example, the "Reset" command will work appropriately.  What Minimum and Maximum values are you looking to have?

Comment: Thanks Lars, now is something clearer. But please, try to do property for Increment, Minimum or/and Maximum (or some of "Decimal" type) same way you do for DecimalPlaces which is "Integer" and you will see that something don't work as it should. By using bounds of Decimal type I try to get NUD's "unlimited" since I do my own validation later. I do never need such big numbers but sometimes I need very good precision in cyclic recalculations with 10 decimals. For that in VB6 I have to use numbers of type "Double". In PostgreSQL database I also store such data in "Double precision" column type.

Comment: "What's unclear to me still is your comment: this set values for all such controls what is not wanted." That is because properties of "Double" type don't behaves "as should" and NUD's start to behave really weird and program change such values "by himself" so I poorly interpret what happening.

Comment: Actually, It seem's that after all I get required functionality with your and Harrison's advices. Only thing is that I can't "Reset" those Decimals from property grid in IDE but that I can survive. Thanks for helping and sorry, I have to give points to Harrison since you have much more than him.